# TexWorks won't recognize style-patterns.txt

Tags: texworks

If I change anything in that file nothing changes in my editor. Colors stay all the same no matter what I do. Any ideas?

The code I used:

```
# TeXworks: Patterns for syntax coloring

# Each entry consists of three whitespace-separated fields:
# <style> <spell?> <regex>

# <style> is a combination of color and style flags
# Valid syntax:
# <fgcolor>
# <fgcolor>/<bgcolor>
# ;<fontflags>
# <fgcolor>;<fontflags>
# <fgcolor>/<bgcolor>;<fontflags>
#
# The color fields <fgcolor> and <bgcolor> are either:
# *) a color name from the list defined in the SVG standard;
#    see https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#ColorKeywords
# *) a hexadecimal color value of the form #rrggbb; note that if this is used at
#    the beginning of a line, a space " " must be added in front of it so the
#    line is not interpreted as a comment (e.g., " #aabbcc" instead of "#aabbcc")
#
# The <fontflags> field is a combination of the letters
# B (bold)
# I (italic)
# U (underlined)

# <spell> is a flag controlling whether this style is subject to spell-checking;
# "Y" or "y" for yes, "N" (or anything else, actually) for no.

# <regex> is the regular expression to match.

# Note that order of rules may be important if several rules could match at the same position;
# this is why the generic "control sequence" rule comes AFTER the specific \begin/\end one.

[LaTeX]
# special characters
springgreen N   [$#^_{}&]

# LaTeX environments
limegreen   N   \\(?:begin|end)\s*\{[^\}]*\}

# LaTeX packages
aqua        N   \\usepackage\s*(?:\[[^\]]*\]\s*)?\{[^\}]*\}

# control sequences
gold        N   \\(?:[\p{L}@]+|.)

# comments
crimson     Y   %.*

[ConTeXt]
# special characters
darkred     N   [$#{}&]

# 'other' special characters
darkblue    N   [=\[\]]

# mathematical operations
gray        N   [\-+/^_]

# start/stop
darkgreen;B N   \\(?:start|stop)[A-Za-z]+

# control sequences
blue;B      N   \\(?:[\p{L}@]+|.)

# comments
red     Y   %.*

[BibTeX]

# entries
darkgreen   N   @[^{]+

# comments
red     Y   %.*

# keys
blue    N   [a-zA-Z]+(?=\s*=)

[LaTeX DTX]

# comments
red     Y   \^\^A.*

# Guards
darkviolet      N   ^%<@@=[^>]*>
limegreen       N   ^%<\*[^>]*>
crimson     N   ^%</[^>]*>
brown       N   ^%<<
orange      N   ^%<[^>]*>

# special characters
darkred     N   \^\^\^\^\^[0-9a-z]{5}
darkred     N   \^\^\^\^[0-9a-z]{4}
darkred     N   \^\^\^[0-9a-z]{3}
darkred     N   \^\^[0-9a-z]{2}
darkred     N   [$#^_{}&]
gray        N   ^%%.*
gray        N   ^%

# Macrocode
lawngreen   N   \\(?:begin|end)\{macrocode\}

# LaTeX environments
lawngreen   N   \\(?:begin|end)\s*\{[^}]*\}

# control sequences
blue        N   \\(?:[\p{L}@:_]+|.)

[Lua]

# Comments (single line only)
red     Y   --.*

# Strings
green       N   (?:\"(?:[^\"\\]|\\[\s\S])*(?:\"|$)|\'(?:[^\'\\]|\\[\s\S])*(?:\'|$))
green       N   \[(=*)\[[\s\S]*(?:\]\1\]|$)

# Keywords
blue;B      N   
\b(?:and|break|do|else|elseif|end|false|for|function|if|in|local|nil|not|or|repeat|return|then|true|until|while)\b

# Numbers
darkblue    N   [+-]?(?:0x[\da-f]+|(?:(?:\.\d+|\d+(?:\.\d*)?)(?:e[+\-]?\d+)?))

# other possibilities to be added....
# [Metapost]
# etc
```

Comment: Did you save the file, quit TeXworks, restart it?

Comment: Obviously did, jep.